# Java conn.getHeaderField("Content-Range") returning wrong size

Tags: java, android, download

I am downloading a file in which I need the size of the file first and then downloading the file in chunks.

But when I am using **connection.getHeaderField("Content-Range")**  it is returning **0-1048575/12927246** in which **/12927246** part is the total size of the file but when I have downloaded the actual file its size is twice of the returned value i.e 1292724*2=25854492.

Can any body explain me the reason or Is there any other way to get the size of the file to be downloaded in chunks?

I am referring this code for downloading :  [Download Code](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/tkb/articleprintpage/tkb-id/java_dev@tkb/article-id/299)